# How connect AWS s3 with Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I am using Docker to save on AWS S3 with this code `docker checkpoint create --checkpoint-dir=s3://bucket-name/ --leave-running=true container_2 checkpoint2` , I am creating a checkpoint called checkpoint2, but when I access my Bucket dont show checkpoint2, how can I send this checkpoint2 to s3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [criu-image-streamer](https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu-image-streamer#example-3-multi-shard-upload-to-the-s3-remote-storage) to connect to S3.

**Checkpoint:**

```sh
sleep 10 & # The app to be checkpointed
APP_PID=$!

# The 'exec N>' syntax opens a new file descriptor in bash (not sh, not zsh).
exec 10> >(lz4 - - | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/img-1.lz4)
exec 11> >(lz4 - - | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/img-2.lz4)
exec 12> >(lz4 - - | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/img-3.lz4)

criu-image-streamer --images-dir /tmp --shard-fds 10,11,12 capture &
criu dump --images-dir /tmp --stream --shell-job --tree $APP_PID
```

**Restore:**

```sh
exec 10< <(aws s3 cp s3://bucket/img-1.lz4 - | lz4 -d - -)
exec 11< <(aws s3 cp s3://bucket/img-2.lz4 - | lz4 -d - -)
exec 12< <(aws s3 cp s3://bucket/img-3.lz4 - | lz4 -d - -)

criu-image-streamer --shard-fds 10,11,12 --images-dir /tmp serve &
criu restore --images-dir /tmp --stream --shell-job
```